# Using Harmon.ie SDK with C#

Tags: c#, sdk, harmon.ie

I use Harmon.ie SDK to copy certain emails to a Sharepoint library. Let me know which object to be used to read email attachments and copy them to SharePoint. Also to know that how can I connect plugin with Outlook and how to debug code.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Our SDK is only exposed to customers running the Enterprise edition. This forum is for our free edition.
If you are customer, please log a request to support@harmon.ie and disclose your company name.

Thanks,

------Jean